# Disable InstallAllUsers property in Web Setup project

Tags: installation, setup-project, web-deployment, setup-deployment, web-setup-project

VS version 2010

Windows client VS Setup project has a property called **InstallAllUsers**. Why don't we have this property in VS Web Setup project ?